# Can camera1394 pakcage change the F-stop value of the camera?

Tags: ros, calibration, camera1394, camera, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can camera1394 pakcage change the F-stop value of the camera? I have Point Grey Firelfy MV work with camera1394 package. But the depth of field is not deep enough. How can I change it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49743/can-camera1394-pakcage-change-the-f-stop-value-of-the-camera?/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2012-12-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The F-stop is a property of the lens, not from the camera. So I do not think it is possible to use the camera1394 to ask or modify the F-stop.

If you want to increase the depth of field, you can change the lens, or close the aperture as much as possible. A smaller aperture means a bigger depth of field, but also means that much less lighting is entering your sensor, so you will have to provide additional light.

---

Originally posted by [BeLioN](https://answers.ros.org/users/2449/belion/) with karma: 126 on 2012-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-12-05**:
Right. The Firefly has a standard CS lens mount. You can adjust the F-stop by hand or swap lenses. But, the DC 1394 standard provides no way for the computer to adjust the F-stop. (It can adjust focus or zoom with some cameras.)

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2012-12-05**:
Thanks for your answer!